# Question about Möbius transformation

Tags: complex-analysis

How to show that only one Möbius transformation which maps three given points to another three given points in the complex plane?

Comment: Let $S$ and $T$ be two such Möbius transformations. Then $R = S^{-1}\circ T$ is a Möbius transformation with at least three fixed points in the plane. Look at the equation for the fixed points of a Möbius transformation to see that that is essentially a quadratic equation, so a Möbius transformation other than the identity can have at most two fixed points.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you want to map the points $z_1,z_2,z_3$ to $w_1,w_2,w_3$ respectively. Since Möbius transformations preserve the cross ratio we have $$(z,z_1,z_2,z_3)=(Tz,w_1,w_2,w_3) $$ for all $z \notin \{z_1,z_2,z_3\}$. This relation determines $Tz$ everywhere except at the points $\{z_k \}$, but thanks to continuity, the extension to $\hat{\mathbb C}$ is unique as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can show that a Möbius transformation is meromorphic and maps circles to circles (where straight lines are considered degenerate circles). If two Möbius transformations have the same image for three points, then they have the same image for a whole circle. The [identity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) implies that they must be the same function.

More boringly, you can start with the assumption $x_i\mapsto y_i$ for $i=1,2,3$ and construct a Möbius transformation satisfying those three conditions, and show that this can be done only in one way, thus proving uniqueness.